# Pandas interpreting datetime wrong

Tags: python, pandas

This probably has a quick answer and I'm being silly, but after one hour of struggling and 3 cups of coffee...

I have this (not very well formatted) time series which is indexing some readings, here's part of it:

```
71670       9/6/16 8:58:1
71671       9/6/16 8:59:1
71672        9/6/16 9:0:1
71673        9/6/16 9:1:1
71674        9/6/16 9:2:1
71675        9/6/16 9:3:1
71676        9/6/16 9:4:1
71677        9/6/16 9:5:1
71678        9/6/16 9:6:1
71679        9/6/16 9:7:1
71680        9/6/16 9:8:1
71681        9/6/16 9:9:1
71682       9/6/16 9:10:1
71683       9/6/16 9:11:1
```

Now this is actually the **9th of June** but when I call pd.to_datetime it interprets this as the 6th of September. How do I tell it what I mean?

Answer (score 4):

Use the dayfirst parameter:

```
pd.to_datetime(df[col], dayfirst=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`to_datetime` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```
pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 1], format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dayfirst` parameter.

```
In [42]: pd.to_datetime('9/6/16 8:58:1', dayfirst=True)
Out[42]: Timestamp('2016-06-09 08:58:01')
```